# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::__toString() must return a string value

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my Student controller:

```
namespace App\HTTP\Controllers;

use App\Student;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class StudentsController extends Controller {

    public static function index(){
        $students = Student::all();
        return view( 'students',compact('students') );

    }
}
```

And my blade view is:

```
{{ $students }}
```

Comment: Nothing is clear in your question. Edit it properly so that everyone can understand what problem you are facing.

Comment: what were you expecting to happen from `{{ $students }}`? just trying to understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{ }}` is for `echo` in php

First check output as

```
 <?php print_r($students); ?>
```

Or

```
 @php 
     print_r($students); 
 @endphp
```

And echo output as, for first row value

```
 {{ $students[0]->name }}
```

And to print all student name in loop like this

```
@forearch($students as $key=>$student)
    Name : {{$student->name}}
@endforearch
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Blade view receive data as (Collection) associate array of students i.e.(Student List) you have to run foreach loop for display student list

```
@foreach($students as $std) 
 <li>{{$std->yourstudent_table_feild_name}}</li> 
@endforeach
```